# flexjson and versioning : how accommodating change is flexjson?

Tags: serialization, deserialization, flexjson

I'm considering using [flexjson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) to serialise my business objects to a file in an android application, simply using JSONSerializer().deepSerialise(myObject) and JSONDeserializer().deserialise(jsonString) with all the default transformers and object factories.

I'm hoping that once the application is released any changes to the business model should be accommodated by writing flexjsons transformers and object factories in the new release to maintain compatibility with previous versions.

What I'm not sure about is what changes the default transformers and object factories can cope with.
i.e if I add a field to a class and deserialise from an old version without the field into the new class will it fail or will the new field be null or 0 (if a number). Same question if I remove a field, what happens.

In standard java serialisation this is all documented here..
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html

But I cant find the equivalent information for flexjson, that deals explicitly with the issues surrounding versioning of objects, Is there any?

Cheers,
Phil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexjson will look at the JSON first to find any fields it contains, and then looks for those fields on the Object you are deserializing into.  So adding new fields to an object will not cause the deserialization process to fail.  The new field will just not be populated from the JSON object (ie it will retain the value(s) set in the constructor or the initialization values).

If you remove a field from an object in the future Flexjson will simply not deserialize that value into the object because it won't find a setter for it.

So you can think about the getter/setter functions as a declaration on the JSON of what you want out of it.  You aren't required to serialize/deserialize all values from the JSON object.

The only part that gets really tricky is if you rename fields, or change types on a field.  Renaming field can be handled by keeping the older setter around and internally setting the new field in that older setter.  You can mark it private or protected to hide it from the outside and Flexjson will still use it.  If you change the type it is much more tricky.  One option is to keep the older setter with the prior type around (like setFoo(String) and setFoo(List)) and adapt to the new type.  The other option is to write your ObjectFactory to translate between to the two potential types.  This of course is the hardest to do.  The last option is don't do this without changing the name of the field, and use one of the other methods to translate.

Comment: Can I ask, does FlexJSON deserialization fail if a extra field is added to the json that is not present in the object?

Comment: It just ignores that field.